# Ignore case while mapping dict items to a pandas series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary which contains around 10 dataframes. With key being the dataframe name

```
dataFramesDict[sheet_1] = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2007-05-30','2107-11-30','2207-05-20','2307-05-20'],'Value': [2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7],'Test': ['Height','Weight','Systolic Blood Pressure Measurement','Diastolic Blood Pressure Measurement']})
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is create a new column called `unit` but by mapping it to a pandas series (`unit_dict`) is a pandas series as shown below. `Term` is the index name.

I am trying to avoid the case sensitivity or make both lower.

[image]

The below code throws error

```
def add_units():
for k in dataFramesDict.keys():
    dataFramesDict[k]['unit'] = dataFramesDict[k]['Test'].str.lower().map(unit_dict.index.str.lower())
print("units are added to the measurements successfully")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rename` with `str.lower` for index of `Series` to `lowercase`:

```
unit_dict = unit_dict.rename(str.lower)
dataFramesDict[k]['unit'] = dataFramesDict[k]['Test'].str.lower().map(unit_dict)

#alternative
unit_dict.index = unit_dict.index.str.lower()
dataFramesDict[k]['unit'] = dataFramesDict[k]['Test'].str.lower().map(unit_dict)
```

Comment: May I know why do we have to use `rename`? Even am using the same alternative answer that you provided but it doesn't work.But in a single line though

Comment: @SSMK - For me it is more neat ;) But if like more another solution, both should working same way